# Heroku from ruby - page does't exist but also exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

After updating to heroku with this command:

1. heroku create
2. git push heroku master
3. heroku run rake db:migrate
4. heroku run rake db:seed

In application.rb config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false and update it but i've got page doesn't exist error.
In production.rb, config.assets.compile = true and push again.

When I "heroku open" http://hw2-mooc.herokuapp.com/

> The page you were looking for doesn't exist. You may have mistyped the
>   address or the page may have moved.

But 
http://hw2-mooc.herokuapp.com/movies is working.

Thanks in advance,
khinelay

Comment: what's in your routes.rb file? What does the log output show?

Comment: in routes.rb, Rottenpotatoes::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :movies
end

Comment: for heroku logs, " !    App not found." after I rename my app from heroku site

Comment: Hello "John Beynon", I type "get remote rm heroku" , "get remote add heroku git@heroku.com:hw-mooc.git" Now I can access my log file. I tried to paste it in this forum but it said it's large. This is what I found out.2013-10-31T19:27:09.756539+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):

Comment: Hello "John Beynon",I got it because of your answer in "routes.rb". I added root :to => redirect('/movies') in routes.rb and now it works. Thanks

Comment: No Problem, a hint is sometimes all you need to fix things yourself.